# How to make two conditions within a DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I am making a report and for this report I need to ensure that two conditions are met within one `DECODE` in Oracle, I have recently known the function `DECODE` and that is why my question arises.

What I have made of me `DECODE` is the following:

```
DECODE (CODE, 'PR', 'Number 1',
              'ES', 'Number 2',
```

For my two conditions to be fulfilled I need him to `CODE` be `'PO'` and also that his `EQUIV` be equal to `85`. These would be the two conditions that I need to be met within `DECODE`, in addition to what I already have working.

Searching in the official Oracle documentation I did not find something similar to what I require [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

Comment: Use a CASE expression instead

Comment: Can you explain how to use the CASE for this particular condition?

Comment: Something like `case when code = 'PO' and equiv = 85 then 'Yes' end` perhaps?

Comment: `decode` is equivalent to `case somevalue when x then y ... else z end`. You can only check against a single value. You could construct something like `decode(code||'::'||equiv, 'PO::85', 'Yes, 'No')` but a `case` expression is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `decode()`.  It is bespoke Oracle syntax.  Since time immemorial (almost), SQL has supported `case` expressions -- which are more flexible than `decode()` and available in all (real) databases.

So, for your code snippet:

```
(CASE WHEN CODE = 'PR'
      THEN 'El Título de '
      WHEN CODE = 'ES'
      THEN 'El Diploma de '
      WHEN CODE = 'PO' AND EQUIV = 85
      THEN 'Jest absolwentem '
 END)
```

You can add any conditions you want to the `WHEN` -- including subqueries if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can I use this CASE within a subquery?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar . . . Definitely.